# MySQL update does not update

Tags: python, mysql

I have a problem that the update mysql part is sometimes not updating a value and it appears to be random I can't find the cause for it. it takes MYSQL entries with key value "TRANSFER" and schould set the same key value to "EXECUTED". Sometimes iI have 20 processes that work fine, sometimes I have 10 processes and half didnt get updated.

```
try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='root',
        passwd='pw',
        db='db',
    )
    db.autocommit(True)

except Exception as e:
    sys.exit("Can't connect to db")

cur = db.cursor()
setstatus = "EXECUTED"
for fn in os.listdir('.'):
     if os.path.isfile(fn):
        UUID = fn.replace(".ac", "")
        try:
            cur.execute("""
                UPDATE olorequest
                SET status = %s
                WHERE UUID = %s
            """, (setstatus, UUID))
        except Exception as e:
            raise IOError(e)
        ftp.storlines('STOR ' + fn, open(fn, 'r+'))
        try:
            shutil.move(fn, executed_ac_files)
        except Exception as e:
            shutil.move(fn, error_files)
            raise IOError(e)
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Let's say there are basically 2 reasons why a line is not updated (apart from technical/connection issues) :
- the `WHERE` predicat was not met
- there's a logical misconception in your program
... which actually is the same :)

Comment: I think that might have actually fixed it. I added `time.sleep(5)` after `UUID = fn.replace(".ac", "")` It could be that the file was still being renamed on the server and UUID has `None` when I update the dB. I run a few tests, thanks so far :)

Comment: You're information lead me to the fix, can you please make answer so I can accept your rightful answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the reason why a row is not updated in an `UPDATE` request is that the predicate of the `WHERE` clause is not met. Additionnaly, as you perform this action through a program, also check its logic and its reliability.